# HTTPS errors - cURL error: SEC_E_WRONG_PRINCIPAL (0x80090322) - The target principal name is incorrect

Tags: ssl, curl, https, openssl

I'm encountering a problem of which I don't know how to fix.

I'm trying to setup an HTTPS server running locally on a Windows host A and have a DNS server running on host B. The DNS server always returns 127.0.0.1, resulting in the URL https://www.somedomain.com referring to the local HTTPS server. However, the problem occurs when trying to connect to the HTTPS server, see the title of this post.

I created a CA certificate:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out rootCA.key 2048
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out rootCA.pem
```

I imported it via mmc.exe as per: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/sdn/articles/installing-the-trusted-root-certificate.

Then, I created a certificate for the domain "www.somedomain.com" (from https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec):

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -nodes -out server.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 500 -sha256 -extfile v3.ext
```

I then run the HTTPS server via Python and check whether it is running with the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe" s_client -showcerts -CAfile C:\Users\[USER]\Desktop\certs\rootCA.pem -servername www.somedomain.com -connect www.somedomain.com:443  | "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe" x509 -inform pem -noout -text
depth=1 C = IN, ST = Random, L = Random, O = Random, OU = Random, CN = Local Certificate, emailAddress = example@domain.com
verify return:1
depth=0 C = DE, ST = State, L = City, O = Organizational name, OU = OU, CN = www.somedomain.com, emailAddress = example@domain.com
verify return:1
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            3a:de:0f:e5:a7:1d:c2:05:26:dd:c6:89:79:6c:bd:79:c9:c8:7e:41
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = IN, ST = Random, L = Random, O = Random, OU = Random, CN = Local Certificate, emailAddress = example@domain.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Sep 20 22:24:07 2022 GMT
            Not After : Feb  2 22:24:07 2024 GMT
        Subject: C = DE, ST = State, L = City, O = Organizational name, OU = OU, CN = www.somedomain.com, emailAddress = example@domain.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:df:93:ce:2a:d5:78:4c:ce:08:18:31:ea:6b:1c:
                    78:d0:2d:25:f8:21:cf:ab:ab:97:dc:70:d1:a5:98:
                    8a:69:9e:f0:b2:45:a4:c8:b7:a5:a1:85:da:5e:cf:
                    19:25:99:87:40:02:d4:20:30:6b:50:2c:88:cd:6c:
                    46:5a:8f:0f:f7:54:69:9a:55:36:15:bc:df:e7:cc:
                    03:06:65:2e:67:f3:f4:69:72:ad:7d:4d:41:d3:40:
                    05:32:8e:54:4f:ff:7d:d5:67:14:eb:86:93:bb:39:
                    9f:e5:e1:2a:fd:e7:8c:3d:e1:ff:31:b8:c2:d7:82:
                    7f:3b:aa:a8:20:93:08:ca:02:6a:8e:0c:bc:c5:c7:
                    cb:88:68:43:78:13:15:bd:fd:57:ee:80:fe:a2:c2:
                    cf:fc:c9:9d:70:29:1b:c3:4c:44:70:f0:96:37:8b:
                    7b:26:fb:0b:a3:85:90:9e:8c:f5:d9:de:ec:17:a1:
                    34:42:ac:f8:a4:03:8a:9e:f9:f8:49:0b:2a:3a:b2:
                    4b:ff:b5:60:d5:08:bb:47:cb:37:2a:07:f9:4d:2b:
                    60:86:ed:48:15:33:70:d8:b3:d0:7c:52:7c:33:51:
                    80:fc:10:3b:11:a1:fd:c8:ff:7a:7c:07:7b:62:53:
                    31:a2:f0:ee:37:cc:9a:d7:3e:71:af:10:28:2e:7e:
                    96:95
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                15:2D:B8:EB:92:7D:AE:58:D7:04:D6:9B:A3:7F:DA:B2:B0:91:13:33
            X509v3 Basic Constraints:
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage:
                Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:www.somedomain.com
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                93:85:39:18:7B:A2:57:2A:1C:B7:3C:E8:B4:56:B3:0F:AE:4A:38:66
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Signature Value:
        5c:4b:90:61:e7:47:62:25:40:4d:95:ec:ac:53:aa:58:dc:1c:
        b0:b6:25:d1:71:f0:67:36:ca:2c:f6:a1:53:54:23:94:63:29:
        9e:18:f7:3c:25:5e:cb:d3:36:f1:47:4f:7b:f4:cd:28:cd:16:
        6f:dd:c4:3f:7d:c2:29:a4:c8:3e:9e:a3:1d:8f:f4:7a:52:67:
        89:38:fa:46:4b:9b:f6:59:17:ba:68:b7:50:4a:92:f1:6d:b0:
        aa:f2:a1:da:4b:df:b8:5d:2e:b5:a3:fc:22:2a:be:c3:39:bb:
        9d:5f:61:c4:32:82:64:2f:8d:f0:e3:82:fa:8f:f5:10:ff:3b:
        55:f7:7d:18:3f:21:9c:4c:09:e8:fa:aa:aa:4c:77:4d:88:92:
        b2:f8:76:3a:04:3e:54:78:d9:0a:7a:4d:06:d7:ef:7f:f0:38:
        45:36:47:4c:fb:73:cd:2c:ea:99:11:b6:5a:3c:4f:c1:5e:3d:
        26:85:bf:4e:2d:9e:13:d0:04:19:77:2d:82:8d:43:9f:4b:58:
        8f:74:d9:7b:52:e3:74:73:36:ec:72:75:3f:c3:ee:92:5b:78:
        ed:55:47:b2:b7:4e:ff:8e:62:46:94:89:70:6b:77:a4:4e:ee:
        cb:9c:df:6d:6f:f0:03:51:2e:e4:1f:54:44:a8:16:e3:0d:91:
        58:a2:a1:8d
```

Unless I specify the *CAfile* parameter, the verification fails, which is also weird to me, since I would think that it should be able to find it in Windows' CA list.

So the Common Name shows the hostname should be "www.somedomain.com", yet when I try to connect to it, this happens:

```
curl -vv https://www.somdomain.com/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:443...
* Connected to www.somdomain.com (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* schannel: ALPN, offering http/1.1
* schannel: SNI or certificate check failed: SEC_E_WRONG_PRINCIPAL (0x80090322) - The target principal name is incorrect.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) schannel: SNI or certificate check failed: SEC_E_WRONG_PRINCIPAL (0x80090322) - The target principal name is incorrect.
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

It seems that the CA is still not trusted, yet it is present when I use mmc.exe. Does someone have an idea where it goes wrong?

Source code of the HTTPS server:

```py
import http.server, ssl

server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 443)
httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(server_address, http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket,
                               server_side=True,
                               certfile='C:\\Users\\[USER]\\Desktop\\certs\\server.crt',
                               keyfile='C:\\Users\\[USER]\\Desktop\\certs\\server.key',
                               ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
print("Running the server...")
try:
    httpd.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
httpd.server_close()
```

Comment: *"since I would think that it should be able to find it in Windows' CA list."* - which is not used by openssl. If curl is using it depends on the kind of TLS backend used - most will not use WindowsCA store either.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, Steffen.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich+ curl using schannel, which this one does, does use Windows store. But openssl doesn't, as you say. (Neither does python, but the python here doesn't need to validate any cert so that doesn't matter.)

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that following each step more carefully resulted in the correct setup I wanted, namely being able to retrieve scripts from my HTTPS server via JScript. I had the wrong domain defined in v3.ext. I know this is a lame answer, but it shows that doing everything again one more time can sometimes solve your problems...

Nevertheless, cURL still complains, but this is not a problem for me per se:

```
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
```

Comment: "I had the wrong domain defined in v3.ext. I know this is a lame answer, but it shows that doing everything again one more time can sometimes solve your problems..." It also shows that if you had given the REAL commands you typed instead of BAD obfuscation, some people could have spotted the problem immediately.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Very much true, @PatrickMevzek, thanks for capitalizing the words, that really helped me.